# Change a div width on window scroll

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-position, onscroll

I'm trying to make a javascript effect on a div like a garage door.
Basically I'd have an absolute div on the back and another div on the front which would shrink from bottom to top base on window school.

I've found a similar jsfiddle, but it's doing it on the width instead on the height and I'd like the div top to stay fixed and shrink from bottom to top.

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/95EtZ/1/)

```
HTML
<div id="added">

<div id="container">
  My center div...
</div>

</div>

CSS
#added { 
    background: #eee;
    height: 2000px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #567;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

JS
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#container').css({
        top: ($(window).height() - $('#container').outerHeight()) / 2
    });
});



// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();


var $scrollingDiv = $("#container");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + 0,
        zeroSizeHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
        newSize = 800 * (1 - (winScrollTop / zeroSizeHeight));

    $scrollingDiv.css({
        width: newSize,
        "marginTop": winScrollTop + "px"
    }, 500, 'easeInOutSine');
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that :

```
var $scrollingDiv = $("#container"),
    defaultHeight = parseInt($scrollingDiv.css('height')); // whatever is in your css as
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + 0,
        zeroSizeHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
        newSize = defaultHeight * (1 - (winScrollTop / zeroSizeHeight));

    $scrollingDiv.css({
        height: newSize,
        "marginTop": winScrollTop + "px"
    }, 500, 'easeInOutSine');
});
```

Comment: Thank Tronix, that's exactly what I want. The only thing now, how to make the text disappear with the div? Big thank you.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, when the div become small, the text should be hidden, isn't it ? Otherwise try adding in CSS: `overflow: hidden` to this div.

Comment: It's working fine now. Also, is it me or it`s not working on chrome or any browser although it works quite fine on JSFiddle. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to include jQuery: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` and put your javascript code within:`jQuery(function($){...your code goes there...});`

Comment: I have copy exactly the same thing I have in JSFiddle, but it's not behaving the way at all. I have the right jQuery library and I've wrap the code inside of jQuery(function($){...}); I still don't get the same result. My doesn't shrink like it should do. I don't know what else to do :s

Answer (score 0):

Set Both to `auto`

CSS

```
#added { 
         background: #eee;
         height: auto;
         width: auto;
       }
```

It automatically add scroll bar no need to apply java script